# Can't I make the prototype function an npm package?

Tags: typescript, npm, prototype

The function of attaching comma to the string was created prototype function.

It works normally within the project, but it does not work normally if it is made into a package and publish.

```
interface StringConstructor {
  toComma(length?: number): string;
  toNumber(): number;
}

interface String {
  toComma(length?: number): string;
  toNumber(): number;
}

String.prototype.toComma = function (length: number = 0) {
  if (this.length == 0 || this == "NaN") return "0";
  const tmp = this.split(".");

  let num = tmp[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",").padZero(length);
  num += tmp.length != 1 && tmp[1].length != 0 ? `.${tmp[1]}` : "";
  return num;
};

String.prototype.toNumber = function () {
  return Number(this.replace(/,/gi, ""));
};
```

and package installed project

```
import "prototype-helper/dist";

console.log("123734123".toComma());
```

Property 'toComma' does not exist on type '"123734123"

Thanks.

Comment: are you emitting declaration files when you build your package? and are you then including those declaration files in the published package? and have you added the `"types"` property to the packages `package.json` correctly?

Comment: @Olian04 Thanks! As you said, it was a problem caused by not declaring `"types"`.